# Character printing out as numbers to std::cout

Tags: c++, arrays, list, loops

I don't understand my problem here. My List on taking the values of the faction and the number seems right. But, there is a problem with my output. Gives me only numbers and no letters to show in what faction they're in.

The statements that are printing numbers are at the bottom, like this one:

```
cout << "Your first Card is "
     << numberBoxListHead_ptr->getNumber()
     << factionHead_ptr->getLetter()
     << endl;
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

//The Class where the List depends on it.
class NumberBox
{
private:

    int number;
    char letter;

public:

    NumberBox *next_ptr;
    void setNumber(int number)
    {
        this->number = number;
    }

    void setLetter(char letter)
    {
        this->letter = letter;
    }


    int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    char getLetter()
    {
        return letter;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int number[4];
    char faction[4];

    NumberBox *factionHead_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *factionBody1_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *factionBody2_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *factionBody3_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *factionTail_ptr = new NumberBox();

    NumberBox *numberBoxListHead_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListBody1_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListBody2_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListBody3_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListTail_ptr = new NumberBox();

    cout << "Please give the number for the first Card" << endl;
    cin >> number[0];
    if(number[0] > 0 && number[0] < 13)
    {
        numberBoxListHead_ptr->setNumber(number[0]); /* <--- Setting for the first input, which is the number */
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Invalid " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Please Give the faction for the first Card" << endl;
    cin >> faction[0];
    if(faction [0] == 's' || faction [0] == 'c' || faction [0] == 'h' || faction [0] == 'd')
    {
        if(faction[0] == 's')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('s');
        }
        else if(faction[0] == 'c')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('c');
        }
        else if(faction[0] == 'h')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('h');
        }
        else if(faction[0] == 'd')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('d');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    cout << "Please give the number for the Second Card" << endl;
    cin >> number[1];
    if(number[1] > 0 && number[1] < 13)
    {
        numberBoxListBody1_ptr->setNumber(number[1]); /* <--- Setting for the second input, which is the number */
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Invalid " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Please Give the faction for the second Card" << endl;
    cin >> faction[1];
    if(faction[1] == 's' || faction[1] == 'c' || faction [1] == 'h' || faction [1] == 'd')
    {
        if(faction[1] == 's')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('s');
        }
        else if(faction[1] == 'c')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('c');
        }
        else if(faction[1] == 'h')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('h');
        }
        else if(faction[1] == 'd')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('d');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Please give the number for the Third Card" << endl;
    cin >> number[2];
    if(number[2] > 0 && number[2] < 13)
    {
        numberBoxListBody2_ptr->setNumber(number[2]); /* <--- Setting for the third input, which is the number */
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Invalid " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Please Give the faction for the Third Card" << endl;
    cin >> faction[2];
    if(faction[2] == 's' || faction[2] == 'c' || faction [2] == 'h' || faction [2] == 'd')
    {
        if(faction[2] == 's')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('s');
        }
        else if(faction[2] == 'c')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('c');
        }
        else if(faction[2] == 'h')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('h');
        }
        else if(faction[2] == 'd')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('d');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Please give the number for the fourth Card" << endl;
    cin >> number[3];
    if(number[3] > 0 && number[3] < 13)
    {
        numberBoxListBody3_ptr->setNumber(number[3]); /* <--- Setting for the fourth input, which is the number */
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Invalid " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Please Give the faction for the fourth Card" << endl;
    cin >> faction[3];
    if(faction[3] == 's' || faction[3] == 'c' || faction [3] == 'h' || faction [3] == 'd')
    {
        if(faction[3] == 's')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('s');
        }
        else if(faction[3] == 'c')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('c');
        }
        else if(faction[3] == 'h')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('h');
        }
        else if(faction[3] == 'd')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('d');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Please give the number for the Fifth Card" << endl;
    cin >> number[4];
    if(number[4] > 0 && number[4] < 13)
    {
        numberBoxListTail_ptr->setNumber(number[4]); /* <--- Setting for the fifth input, which is the number */
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Invalid " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Please Give the faction for the fifth Card" << endl;
    cin >> faction[4];
    if(faction[4] == 's' || faction[4] == 'c' || faction [4] == 'h' || faction [4] == 'd')
    {
        if(faction[4] == 's')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('s');
        }
        else if(faction[4] == 'c')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('c');
        }
        else if(faction[4] == 'h')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('h');
        }
        else if(faction[4] == 'd')
        {
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter('d');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //This would be the list for the value of the card.

    numberBoxListHead_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListBody1_ptr; /* <--- From Head to Body1 */
    numberBoxListBody1_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListBody2_ptr; /* <--- From Body1 to Body2 */
    numberBoxListBody2_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListBody3_ptr; /* <--- From Body2 to Body3 */
    numberBoxListBody3_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListTail_ptr; /* <--- From Body3 to BodyTail */

    //This Would be the list for the faction of the card.

    factionHead_ptr->next_ptr = factionBody1_ptr; /* <--- From Head to Body1 */
    factionBody1_ptr->next_ptr = factionBody2_ptr; /* <--- From Body1 to Body2 */
    factionBody2_ptr->next_ptr = factionBody3_ptr; /* <--- From Body2 to Body3 */
    factionBody3_ptr->next_ptr = factionTail_ptr; /* <--- From Body3 to BodyTail */

    int counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++)
    {
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            cout << "Your first Card is " << numberBoxListHead_ptr->getNumber() << factionHead_ptr->getLetter() << endl;
        }
        if(counter == 1)
        {
            cout << "Your Second Card is " << numberBoxListBody1_ptr->getNumber() << factionBody1_ptr->getLetter() << endl;
        }
        if(counter == 2)
        {
            cout << "Your third Card is " << numberBoxListBody2_ptr->getNumber() << factionBody2_ptr->getLetter() << endl;
        }
        if(counter == 3)
        {
            cout << "Your fourth Card is " << numberBoxListBody3_ptr->getNumber() << factionBody3_ptr->getLetter() << endl;
        }
        if(counter == 4)
        {
            cout << "Your fifth Card is " << numberBoxListTail_ptr->getNumber() << factionTail_ptr->getLetter() << endl;
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int getLetter()
```

This is wrong in this case. `letter` is a char, make sure you return a char if you want it to be printed as a letter.

```
char getLetter() { ... }
```

If you return an `int`, `std::cout` will print it numerical value just like it does for the card rank. If you return a `char`, it will print the corresponding character, not its numerical value.

(Your code needs a serious refactoring work. Make functions to handle inputting the suit, and the rank, and reuse those functions. Then figure out how to do a loop to read the four cards.)

Comment: Just one last thing. The second until the fifth card doesn't show the letter.

Comment: You'll need to debug that yourself, the code is very hard to follow since it repeats itself so much and you have arrays for some things and named variables for others. So you'll need to fix that yourself. But just look at your code, and check whether you're ever setting rank or suit for the factionBodyX_ptr variables.

Comment: How I felt so stupid. In all of my faction, are "factionHead_ptr->setLetter"

Thank you so much! Mat!